# How to store/track a url and then submit based on what is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a filter page where I can select an option and outline it.

I need help figuring out how to store the URL path without it actually going to that page until the check box is selected in the corner.

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="media-select-option" id="media-all"><a href="media/latest/news/">All</a></li>
    <li class="media-select-option" id="media-photos"><a href="media/latest/photos/news/">Photos</a></li>
    <li class="media-select-option" id="media-videos"><a href="media/latest/videos/news/">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.overlaymedia {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 500;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
.overlaymedia.active {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.m-overlay-close-btn:before { 
    content: ''; 
    background: url('/static/images/close2x.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    font: 100 12px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: #333;
    right: 0px;
}
.m-overlay-close-btn.checked:before {
    content: '';
    background: url('/static/images/icon-accept2x.png') 5px 5px no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    font: 100 12px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: #333;
}
.m-overlay-close-btn {
    position: fixed;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    /*background: rgba(255,255,255, .13) url('/static/images/close.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;*/
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:100;
}
.m-close-main-nav, .m-overlay-close-btn.bottom {
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    /*background: url('/static/images/overlay-close-btn.png') 0 0 no-repeat;*/
    background-size: 18px 18px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: #333;
    font: 100 12px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
}
.media-select-option {
    border: solid 2px #000;
}
.selected {
    border: solid 2px rgb(102, 102, 102);
    color: rgb(94, 161, 252);
}
```

### JS

```
$('.media-select-option').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected')
    $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked'); 
});
```

## jsFiddle

Comment: can you post html and js code rather than putting css?
Its hard to understand that what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, just added that.

Comment: @user2386255 updated answer with full explination of problems as well as 2 alternate solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this.you will get the  url and prevent the from redirecting

```
$(function() {
    $('.media-select-option a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent from redirecting
        alert($(this).attr('href')); //get the url
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected')
        $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so how do I add that URL to m-overlay-close-btn?

Comment: firstly save the url as **var url=$(this).attr('href')**; then **$('.m-overlay-close-btn').html(url);**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the url, you can retrieve it with the "selected" class name. if your checkbox's id is myCb, you can do:

```
$('.media-select-option').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected')
    $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked'); 
});
$('#myCb').click(function(e){
    document.location=$('.selected').children('a').attr('href');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small collective of problems here. Nothing major. First of all, you are selecting a `li` when trying to use `e.preventDefault`. This will not prevent the link from changing the page because `e.preventDefault` is going to act on the `li`, **not** the `a`. The next problem is that `preventDefault` is a function, but you're using it as a variable. Remember to use `()` on methods. The last couple problems I'll just show you.

### Problem Code

```
//  your first problem is here, this selector grabs a "li" not an "a" tag
$('.media-select-option').click(function(e) {
    //  thus, the following will not prevent anything and the link will still follow
    e.preventDefault;
    //  Second, preventDefault is a method, this requires "()" at the end of it
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    //  if you want this added to the "li",
    //      then you'll need to change selector here,
    //          when you change main selector
    $(this).addClass('selected')
    $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked'); 
});
```

My proposed solution will make it much easier to follow as well as prepare for possible dynamic links added after page load. Like so:

### A Solution

```
//  the selector i use grabs the link itself
$(document).on("click", ".media-select-option a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent link from changing page
    var $this = $(this),    //  simple variable to constantly refer to this "A" tag link
        li = $this.closest("li").addClass("selected"),  //  get the parent "LI" this "link" belongs too
        href = $this.attr("href");  //  grab URL of link in case you need it later in function
    $(".selected").not(li).removeClass("selected"); //  not(li) will ensure it only removes it from other links
    $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');
    //  if you wanted to change the page now you could do something like:
    //  location.href = href;
})
```

## Working Example

---

### Suggested Solution

On another note, you could make the `click` event available to both parent `LI` and child `A`. Just use `e.target.tagName` to determine which item is being called. It is as simple as:

```
//  this selector grabs both links and their parents
$(document).on("click", ".media-select-option, .media-select-option a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //  prevent links from going
    e.stopPropagation();    //  preent click on both link and li, only one click needs processing

    //  establish usable variables
    var $a, $href, $li;
    //  set variables based on which item is being clicked
    switch(e.target.tagName){
        case "A":
            $a = $(this);
            $li = $a.closest("li").addClass("selected");
            break;
        case "LI":
            $li = $(this).addClass("selected");
            $a = $li.children("a");
            break;
    }
    //  Here you have your link!
    $href = $a.attr("href");  //  put this variable where you want

    $(".selected").not($li).removeClass("selected");    //  not(li) will ensure it only removes it from other links
    $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');  //  your old call, not sure what this is for
})
```

## Working Example